# Deserialize Xml Attributes

Tags: c#, xmlparser

Добрый день.

Есть `XML` в виде :

```
<billers  Col1Name="Key" Col2Name="Value">
    <MethodsList>
        <Method Name="строка вызова" type="Concatenate" ReadOnly="true" FieldName="@GMProp" Delimiter=""/>
    </MethodsList>
    <FieldsList>
        <Field label="ServiceId" Type="Целое число" IsObligatory="true" Visible="false" Value="294" MethodName="строка вызова" Long="12"/>
        <Field label="@Prop" Visible="false" Value="msisdn=38" MethodName="строка вызова"/>
        <Field label="Телефон" IsObligatory="true" Value="044" MethodName="строка вызова" Stored="F1" FinderID="true" Long="10"/>
        <Field label="ФИО" Type="ФИО" Stored="F2"/>
        <Field label="@GMProp" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false"/>
        <Field label="Сумма пополнения" Type="Дробное число" IsObligatory="true" Summable="true" Long="10,2"/>
        <Field label="@доп" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false" Value="; " MethodName="строка вызова"/>
    </FieldsList>
</billers>
```

Нужно ее десериолизовать.

Делаю так:

Есть соответствующие классы :

```
[Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("billers")]
    public class OrganizationControl
    {
        [XmlArray("MethodsList")]
        [XmlArrayItem(typeof(OrganizationMethod))]
        public List<OrganizationMethod> GetOrganizationMethods { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("FieldsList")]
        [XmlArrayItem(typeof(OrganizationField))]
        public List<OrganizationField> GetOrganizationFields { get; set; }

        public OrganizationControl()
        {
            GetOrganizationMethods = new List<OrganizationMethod>();
            GetOrganizationFields = new List<OrganizationField>();
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("Field")]
    public class OrganizationField  
    {
        [XmlAttribute("label")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public bool IsObligatory { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Value { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Mask { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public decimal Long { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string MethodName { get; set; }

        private bool _visible = true;
        [XmlAttribute]
        public bool Visible
        {
            get
            {
                return _visible;
            }
            set
            {
                _visible = value;
            }
        }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("Method")]
    public class OrganizationMethod
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string FilterField { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string AddParams { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Delimiter { get; set; }
    }
```

И класс для десериализации :

```
public static class Serializer<T>
    {
        public static T Deserialize(string value)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value)))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
    }
```

Строчка десериализации :

```
OrganizationControl orgControl = Serializer<OrganizationControl>.Deserialize(xml);
```

Такая реализация не работает. Данные не десериализируются и списки Methods и Fields не заполняются.

Вопрос: что я делаю не так?

Спасибо.

Comment: А что именно значит «не работает»? Выбрасывается исключение или молча возвращается пустой объект? Попробуйте упростить ваш класс до одного атрибута и перепроверить.

Comment: Данные не десериализируются и списки Methods и Fields не заполняются.

Comment: @Telsystems: а если упростить класс до одного атрибута?

Comment: тоже самое. почему-то не отрабатывает десиарилизация.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось решить заменой

`[XmlArrayItem(typeof(OrganizationMethod))]`

`[XmlArrayItem(typeof(OrganizationField))]`

на

`[XmlArrayItem("Method")]`

`[XmlArrayItem("Field")]`